# Retina Display in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

Fonts in Cincom Smalltalk VisualWorks 7.10 are not displayed in high resolution on a MacBook Pro with Retina display. Setting Text Size to "Large" does not solve the problem. Screen default resolution is 75@75. Why is "Screen default resolution: 300 @ 300." not working?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that VisualWorks performs its own double buffering independent of the OS buffering.  Instead of changing the font size to one that's appropriately larger, VW renders onto a bitmap which is then scaled to fit the screen producing suboptimal results.

This issue is being investigated by Cincom and should be fixed in a future release.  I have no information which release that would be at this time.